# None of his sons could land a job in the government service

Tags: difference, past-tense, modal-verbs

1. None of his sons **could** land a job in the government service. (*Here we're talking only about the past*)
2. None of his sons **was/were able to** land a job in the government service.

Do (1) and (2) mean exactly the same thing? If not, what would be the difference, please?

**Note**: I know that to some "**was** able to" seems correct, and to others, "**were** able to". So, in the present thread, I'm not really concerned about them/their difference.

Comment: Have you looked up "could", "able" and "manage" in dictionaries? Tell us what you found, and what about those definitions still isn't clear to you

Comment: Also, comparing the structures "could", "be able to" and "manage" is a different question from comparing *simple past* and *present perfect*, and so makes this question off-topic. The difference between those two tenses is very well covered on this site already (it even has its own tag), so I recommend editing tense comparisons out of your question

Comment: ........edited.

Comment: @gotube, "could" is not "was/were able to" in every context. That's why I ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

1 is somewhat different in that it doesn't actually require that the son(s) even apply for such a position. 2 and 3 require such an attempt, I would tend to red 3 as the attempt is on-going but so far unsuccessful, where in 2 the attempt has been terminated.